# Should I create the deep copy of Vue component parameter?

Tags: vue.js

From Vue documentation:

> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one: when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but not the other way around.

However, if to pass the nested object or array from parent's `data` as child component's parameter and child will change it, the data of parent will change, too.

Ideally, good framework must take care about deep copying when required, but Vue does not. 
The one of solution is creating the copy based on parameter's value. Should I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "as child component's parameter"?

Comment: @Michael, sorry for poor English. "Pass to child component as parameter" will be correct?

Comment: you mean a route parameter? Aren't props parameters?

Comment: @Michael No. For example,` <Child :payload="nestedData">` where `nestedData` is from parent's `data: function() { return { foo: "alpha", nestedData: { bar: "bravo" } } }`. Here, the `nestedData` passed as parameter naming `payload`.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think creating copy is a good solution as far as i know.
The best practice for your task is to use [.sync](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-sync) modifier!

Comment: If anything now I would stay away from that it is being deprecated in vue3

Comment: @Michael didnt know that. i wonder how they are going to solve child mutating prop problem. .sync modifier is a really clean solution